# Using an Audio Signal for a Control Voltage for an Analog Synthesizer

Tags: voltage, analog, music, synthesizer

I have a Moog Sub 37 Analog Synthesizer and a Korg SV-1 keyboard. Can I take the audio out of either the line outs or headphone out of the Korg and plug it into the volume or filter Control Voltage (CV) in of the Sub 37 to affect those controls as a control voltage? Moogs take a +/-5V CV signal. I'd just go ahead and do it but I don't want to damage anything.

If that can't be done directly, is there a way to convert an audio signal into a control voltage signal?

Comment: What do you hope to achieve? You'll be modulating at audio frequency so expect it to be horrible. Do you want to modulate one with the volume of the other?

Comment: Yes. If the line outs are within the safe voltage, you can do this. It may or may not do what you want : using raw audio would produce a vocoder kind of effect (like having a Dalek on lead vocals). You may want to rectify the audio to "envelope detect" it and filter that, to make a noise gate (so the instrument sings along with you) - there are almost certainly synth modules to do this for you.

Comment: Ok, yes I'm really just seeing what I can do with it at this point. I did just try it. If I put it into the filter CV input and hold a note on the Moog while I play notes on the Korg, you can hear it FM the filter so you can hear the notes I'm playing. It also has affect on the pitch and some what on the volume. It only works on the gate if you turn the volume up a lot. I think that's because the gate is a binary 5v or 0.